# limit ForeignKey choices based on another ForeginKey field

Tags: django, django-forms, foreign-keys, limit-choices-to

Let's say I have an app's structure that looks like this :

** models.py **

```
Class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)


Class Manager(models.Model)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=500)
    school = models.ForignKey(School)


Class Group(models.Model)
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=500)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager, related_name="group_manager")
```

In the template I want users to be able to create groups (in the school page) and choose among managers who belong to the same school only!

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a table with 2 foreign keys and one name it probably should be a through table for ManyToMany relation between Shool and Manager.

```
Class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    managers = models.ManyToMany(Manager, through='Group')
```

Comment: isn't there a way to do it using ForeignKey?

Comment: In your schema, one Group can have refer to one School and one Manger. But as I understand there could be more than one Magnaer per School.

Comment: What if there would be one manager per school? How can I do it?

Comment: In that case, The most simple way is to make for loop in template through all the Managers and show managers only from that school.